# Why a div after a <header> is not displaying under the header?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm doing a reactJS web application, i have done the header but when i want to add a div for the content after the header, the div is not displaying under the header and I don't understand why

Which is weird is that when i put my div in the header, the div is displayed normaly under the previous element

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <Header/>
        </header>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Real}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/makingof" component={MakingOf}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

this is my app and this is my simple  component

```
class Real extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="divReal">
                <p>real</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Condensed:600&display=swap');

.Header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 20vh;
}

img {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%
}

.iconWrapper {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.network {
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.network:not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem !important;
}

.network:hover {
    color: grey !important;
}

.iconTest {
    color: red !important;
}

.navBar {
    margin: 0 auto;;
    width: 50%;
    height: 4.4vh;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.menuNavBar {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 4vh !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

.test {
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.test:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
    .navBar {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .menuNavBar {
        height: 4vh !important;
    }
}
```

[image: the 'real Component' on the left is the div i would like to display under the header]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libraries or can you check if your CSS is making `header { display: none; }` or visibility to hidden?

Comment: Does the div show up in the markup? I assume 'Real' is the <Header /> component? If not, does <Header /> use fragments?

Comment: I just add a picture of my app the Header component is the Logo, the social network logo and the navigations bar between the two black lines, the real component text is the div which I don't unerstand why she is display here (I would like to display it under the header)

Comment: My header component dont have a display css, what do you mean by 'fragments' ? thanks for your help

Comment: We need to see your header elements' CSS, you might be using position:absolute; on some elements in the header.

Comment: just add it in the post

Comment: Are the social media icons floated or anything?

Comment: I found the source of the problem and i just described it in a new post below

Answer (score 0):

Error on :::

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Real}></Route>
```

Try this :::

```
<Route exact path="/real" component={Real}></Route>
```

react default load `/` Route, So u can change this format.

Comment: no I want to load the Real component on "/" route, the component is display but in a weird zone :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just find the origin of the problem, as you can see in the screen below,the new component is well display under the "header" div, but some element in the "header" come out of the div
Do you know how I can fix that ?
[image]

```
return (
            <div className="Header">
                <img src={logo} alt="" className="logo"></img>
                <div className="iconWrapper">
                    <Icon link className="network" name="instagram" size="big" onClick={() => this.openLink('https://www.instagram.com/wissiz/')}/>
                    <Icon link className="network" name="youtube" size="big" onClick={() => this.openLink('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBdPpMiCdn6BnTWG-b3GW2g')}/>
                    <Icon link className="network" name="facebook" size="big" onClick={() => this.openLink('https://www.facebook.com/wissiz')}/>
                </div>
                <div className="navBar">
                    <Menu className="menuNavBar" borderless fluid widths={3}>
                        <Menu.Item className="test" name='société' fitted onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>REALISATIONS</Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item className="test" name='société' fitted onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/contact')}>CONTACT</Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item className="test" name='société' fitted onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/makingof')}>MAKING OF</Menu.Item>
                    </Menu>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Here my header div